# Getting unexpected results from a join query

Tags: mysql

So I have the following `query` for `mysql` db

```
SELECT CFM.display_name, CFM.field_type, CFM.option_value
FROM company_mast
LEFT JOIN component_mast ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID
AND CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
WHERE component_mast.component_name =  'Assets'
AND component_mast.project_id =  '1'
```

and it returns exactly what I want. I can also query like this

```
SELECT CFM.display_name, CFM.field_type, CFM.option_value
FROM company_mast
LEFT JOIN component_mast ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID
AND CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
WHERE component_mast.component_name =  'Assets'
AND company_mast.company_name =  'Company' <!-- this line is different -->
```

Again it returns exactly what I want. Yet if I run this query

```
SELECT CFM.display_name, CFM.field_type, CFM.option_value
FROM company_mast
LEFT JOIN component_mast ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID
AND CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
WHERE component_mast.component_name =  'Assets'
AND component_mast.project_id =  '1'
AND company_mast.company_name =  'Company'
```

I get 0 results. Now for the present, this is working, but as this database grows there will be multiple components with the same name in the same company. So I need to add an extra unique identifier, which is project_id.

Why isn't the third query returning what the first two are? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need an `or` condition instead of an `and` condition:

```
SELECT CFM.display_name, CFM.field_type, CFM.option_value
FROM company_mast
LEFT JOIN component_mast ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID
AND CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
WHERE component_mast.component_name =  'Assets'
AND (component_mast.project_id =  '1' or company_mast.company_name =  'Company')
```

Comment: Thanks, for the extra pair of eyes. I guess the logic just escaped me momentarily. It worked, answer will be accepted asap